# Excluding specific items in a collection when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to "cherry-pick" which objects in a collection of a specific type I want to serialize.

Example setup:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    ...

    public bool ShouldSerialize { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to exclude all the courses in the Person.Courses collection where ShouldSerialize is false. This needs to be done from within the ContractResolver - the ShouldSerialize property is an example, in my real scenario there may be other criteria. I'd prefer not having to create a ShouldSerializeCourse (as specified here: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm )

I can't seem to find out which method to override in the ContractResolver. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can filter a list using a ContractResolver, but you could do it using a custom JsonConverter.  Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person 
            {
                Name = "John",
                Courses = new List<Course>
                {
                    new Course { Name = "Trigonometry", ShouldSerialize = true },
                    new Course { Name = "History", ShouldSerialize = true },
                    new Course { Name = "Underwater Basket Weaving", ShouldSerialize = false },
                }
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Georgia",
                Courses = new List<Course>
                {
                    new Course { Name = "Spanish", ShouldSerialize = true },
                    new Course { Name = "Pole Dancing", ShouldSerialize = false },
                    new Course { Name = "Geography", ShouldSerialize = true },
                }
            }
        };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new CourseListConverter());
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

class CourseListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<Course>));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ((List<Course>)value).Where(c => c.ShouldSerialize).ToArray());
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool ShouldSerialize { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Courses": [
      {
        "Name": "Trigonometry"
      },
      {
        "Name": "History"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Georgia",
    "Courses": [
      {
        "Name": "Spanish"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Geography"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect! Ill have to modify for my scenario of course. :)

Comment: it's a pretty subtle thing, the fact that the `ToArray` after the `Where` clause prevents a stack overflow by changing the collection type.  I started with an array, thus did `ToList`

Comment: I used this solution with a tweak that may be helpful. I created a one-off subclass of `List<T>` called `FilteredList`, then excluded its type in `CanConvert()` and wrapped the filtered list in the `FilteredList` when passing to the `Serialize()` method in `WriteJson()`.  Specifically, the body of `CanConvert()` looks like `typeof(FilteredList) != objectType && typeof(IList<MyType>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)`. That way, the input can be a List or Array or any other IList, but it won't accidentally go into a recursive stackoverflow when trying to convert its own output.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, which work on .NET 6:

```cs
public class CourseConverter : JsonConverter<Course>
{
    public override Course? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Course>(reader.GetString()??"");

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Coursevalue, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value.ShouldSerialize)
           JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
       //otherwise just ignore it...
    }
}
```

usage:

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new();
jsonOptions.Converters.Add(new CourseConverter ());
var json =  JsonSerializer.Serialize(sourceObject,typeof(Course),jsonOptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not put the logic into serializer. Instead filter the collection and then serialize it. In this case, you may use something like this

```
Person.Courses = Person.Courses.Where(t=> t.ShouldSerialize == false);

return Person;
```

If you really need to add the contract resolver into your serializer you may do it in your Global.asax.cs (assuming you are using asp.net)

Comment: The problem is being able to do the "filtering" from within the contract resolver.

Comment: Also, doing it this way would modify the source object, which in my case is undesirable.

Comment: Since you are using Json.Net the only thing you can do is to create ShouldSerializeX ShouldSerializeY methods in order to check if it is going to be serialized.. What do you mean "this modify the source object"? It works only on serialization I guess.

Comment: By settings `Person.Courses = ...` the original Person.Courses is lost, of course unless I save it in a temp variable first.. which I guess is acceptable. Oh well.

Comment: :) I think modifying the source object just before serializing is an easier way to do this. Because you may not need the property in a service but another service call. If you are gonna do with the link you have provided, you need to create another entity for it which is a workload for you :)

Comment: One could make an alternate property just for serializing. The getter would return `Person.Courses.Where(t => t.ShouldSerialize)` and the setter would just set `Person.Courses = value`.  Mark this one `[JsonProperty]` and/or mark Person.Courses `[JsonIgnore]`, as appropriate.