# Ignore NULL values in JsonConvert.Deserialize or JToken.Parse

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

For example, I have following JSON: `{"a":null}` and I want to deserialize it to Newtonsoft's `JToken`.

I tried `JToken jt = JToken.Parse(json)` and `JToken jt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })` but both produce `jt["a"] != null` and `jt["a"].Type == JTokenType.Null`. Is it possible to make `jt["a"] == null`? Or maybe I'm asking some kind of nonsense?

Comment: What do you want to get when you do `JToken.Parse(json)`?  An empty `JObject` with no properties?  Or a `JObject` with one property whose value is `null`?  If you want the latter then that is not possible, see [Newtonsoft Json.Net serialize JObject doesn't ignore nulls, even with the right settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29258587) and [Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/3744182).

Comment: But if you want an empty object that might be possible, see [JSON.NET serialize JObject while ignoring null properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028482/3744182) for one possible way.

Comment: @dbc I want `jt["a"] == null`, so there will be no difference on my side in handling of `{"a":null,"b":100}` and `{"b":100}`. This is the real situation. Sometimes third-party API sends null, sometimes it skips the property at all.

Comment: Then the easiest thing to do would be to remove properties with null values afterwards, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33028482/3744182) by Brian Rogers to [JSON.NET serialize JObject while ignoring null properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33027409/3744182). Does that answer your question?