# Read a JSON property with NULL handling using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON structure  like below to show the details of a specific candidate
It can be either null or can contain some details like below

```
     "details": {
        "gender": {
          "id": 3,
          "props": {
            "name": "male"
          }
        }
    }

    or as null

    "details": {
        "gender": null
    }
```

To read the value of gender i tried

```
 string _gender = (string)result["details"]["gender"]["props"]["name"];
```

This will works in non null cases . But if its null then this code returns an exception

So  to check first is it null or not and if not null try to read the value, i tried below code

```
        string _gender = (string)result["details"]["gender"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gender))
        {
            _gender = (string)result["details"]["gender"]["props"]["name"]; 
        }
```

But i am getting the exception that not possible to convert object to string. So how  to read a JSON property with proper null handling \

Comment: Why not deserialize it to a type where gender is nullable ?

Comment: gender is just a property from a JArray .

Comment: You could still deserialize it. If you use [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/) with your complete json you could then make the type of `details` nullable and deserialize your json to an object e.g. `List<YourObject>`. Then fetch the details property for all instances.

Comment: the json is of dynamic in nature, So its hard to set all the nullable and non-nullable properties for the entire json parsing. This gender is just one of the property i am struggling to parse. And i am trying to find a olution to handle null in this way

Comment: Maybe just `if(result["details"]["gender"] != null)` ? Remember that  `result["details"]["gender"]` is of type JToken, not string

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Json.NET get nested jToken value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42290485/3744182).  Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that `jToken[xx..][yy..]` is *not* a string, it is a JToken object, therefore we cannot explicitly cast it to string. If we want to convert it to string we'd have to call `ToString()` on it explicitly (which in terms calls JToken's overridden implementation of `.ToString`).

First we need to check that Jtoken has values for that we have method `.HasValues`.
Later when we know for certain that there is a string in ["name"] 
property we can use either - explicit cast or `.ToString()` again

```
string _gender;
var genderToken = jToken["details"]["gender"];
if (genderToken.HasValues)
{
    _gender = genderToken["props"]["name"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to deserialize the json as known type.

```
public class Props
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Props props { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public Gender gender { get; set; }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public Details details { get; set; }
}
```

Then perform deserialization;

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonObject>>(json);
foreach (var o in jsonObject)
{
    var genderName = o?.details?.gender?.props?.name;
}
```

In this way, you can handle the possible null values and get strongly typed object.

**EDIT**

Also, in your code, you are trying to convert an object to string and it is completely wrong. It seems that `gender` object is a complex type. So you can't convert it to string and you should modify your code like this;

```
object _gender = result["details"]["gender"];
if (_gender != null)
{
    string genderName = result["details"]["gender"]["props"]["name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: sorry the json is of highly dynamic in nature, So its hard to set all the nullable and non-nullable properties on  the entire json for parsing. This gender is just one of the property i am struggling to parse. And i am trying to find a solution to solve nullable JToken parsing basically