# Check if property or parent property exist with Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Is there any way to check if a property or a properties parent exist in Json.NET?

For example:
If the json looks like this:

```
{
'name': 'Sensor1',
'active': true,
'deviceId': 123,
'stats': {
    'temp': 10,
    'humidity': 50,
    'wind': 2
}
```

It is possible to check if temp exist like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
double? temp = data["stats"]["temp"]; //returns null if temp does not exist
```

But if the parent to temp (stats) is missing, an exception occurs and null is not returned.

To summarize: is it possible, given the example, to check if temp or the parent property exists (or simply put if stats.temp exist)?

I realize that I can check stats first and then temp but the json I am dealing with is far more complex than this example.

**Update:**

I was able to achieve what i wanted using SelectToken("pathToProperty") like this:

```
JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
JToken jt = obj.SelectToken("stats.temp");
```

SelectToken returns value if found, otherwise null.

Comment: `I realize that I can check stats first and then temp but the json I am dealing with is far more complex than this example.` Please update your example to be of equivalent complexity.

Comment: mjwills: The example is representative, what i meant by more complex is that it contains hundreds of properties (on different levels) and it would be tedious work to check if every level exist. I would like to check if property1.property2.property3 exist instead of checking them all independently.

Comment: Not sure if this will work in your case but have you looked at [TryGetValue](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm)

Comment: It seem like it'd be trivial to write a function that takes a dynamic object and an array of property names (or even a string and then split by a delimiter, such as `"prop1.prop2.prop3"`), then walk down the array until either you hit a null or get to the end of the array and return a value. You could even make it generic so that it handles casting for you.

Comment: Would a `try..catch` be useful?         `public static object GetValue(Func<object> getValue)
        {
            try
            {
                return getValue();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        } `

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I think i might be able to achieve what i want using SelectToken("stats.temp"). It will return the value if it exists, otherwise null.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Json.NET get nested jToken value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42290485).