# C# XML serialize specific elements from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization

I would like to serialize some specific elements of an array based on some condition.

For Example:

```
public class Team 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}  
    public Person[] Staff;}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public NrOfHolidays {get; set;}
}
```

And when serializing the `Team` class I would like to serialize only those members from the `Staff` array that have a `NrOfHolidays` larger than 10 let's say.

Is there a way this can be done?

I know how the `ShouldSerialize[MemberName]` function can be used to serialize/not serialize a given member, but I don't know if it can be applied to elements of an array that is a member.

Edit:
Thanks for the replies.

I just found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955722/excluding-specific-items-in-a-collection-when-serializing-to-json).
This is the exact same problem I'm facing, but the solution proposed here is for JSON. I'm looking for a solution similar to the on proposed in the above post, which works for XML serialization.

Comment: Simply filter the array before serializing it with a LINQ query

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the array as not serializable and then create a property for serialization which filters that array with a linq query:

```
public class Team 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}  
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public Person[] Staff{ get; set; }
    public Person[] SerializationStaff
    {

        get
        { 
              return Staff == null ? null : Staff.Where(s => s.NrOfHolidays > 10).ToArray(); 
        }

        set
        {
             Staff = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int NrOfHolidays {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Nice solution without any further external changes to be done. However you may replace the `SerializationStaff`-tag-name by the appropriate one using `XmlElement("Staff")`

Comment: Indeed you can and can be a very good improvement, but for clarity i think it's better to leave this example code as is.

Comment: It doesn't, at least using XmlSerializer which this code is intended for. Binary serialization is a really bad idea, when your project changes it's version it will stop working (at least without workarounds),

Comment: Thanks for the response, your solution indeed solves the problem at hand, but I was looking for something like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955722/excluding-specific-items-in-a-collection-when-serializing-to-json that works with XML Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you create a new team including only those `Person`s that have the condition:

```
var newTeam = new Team(myTeam.Staff.Where(x => x.Holidays > 10));
```

Assuming you have a constructor for `Team` which expects a set of `Person`. Now you can serialize that team instead of the original one.

If not use the default-ctor and set the property afterwards:

```
var newTeam = new Team();
newTeam.Stuff = myOldTeam.Staff.Where(...);
```

This won´t need any changes on your `Team`-class, however you have to do some little work on the client-side.