# How to ignore null array elements with Newtonsoft JSON serializer

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm attempting to serialize an object array, but I need it to ignore null elements. I realize I could simply have logic upon deserialization that checks for the nulls, however I don't want to write unnecessary data over the network. The array can have a maximum of 9 elements, but all 9 indices are not used in every instance. I understand that a list could be utilized, but for efficiency sake I do not wish to do that.

Per similar questions I've browsed on this site, I've attempted to add the following tag to the array: `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`

However, this approach does not ignore null elements.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public Node[] Nodes { get; } 
public void Init() 
{
    Nodes = new Node[9];
}
public string Encode()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Nodes, Formatting.None);
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` will ignore property when its **value** is null. In your case the value of `Nodes` property is `Node[9]` array. Does `Nodes = Nodes.Where(n => n != null).ToArray();` fits your needs in `Encode()` method?

Comment: When the data is deserialized at the receiving end, how  do you expect the data to be reconstructed without the index data?i.e Node[4]{Node,null,null,Node} Node[4]{Node,Node,null,null}

Comment: @vasily.sib That's definitely a solution, however I was hoping that there was a way for the serializer to just skip the null entries. I would prefer not to instantiate a new array if not necessary.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü The Node object has an Index property that takes care of that.

Comment: @JackMyStack, then you do not need to use `new Node[9];` use `List` or something that works for you such as `HashSet` if all your nodes are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to filter the array just before you serialize it.  You can do this in your `Encode` method, without instantiating a new array:

```
public string Encode()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Nodes.Where(n => n != null), Formatting.None);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dj8lnP

If you don't like that idea, for whatever reason, you can use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) similar to  the one in [Excluding specific items in a collection when serializing to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20955722/10263) to do the filtering.