# Newtonsoft.Json: Ignore specific entries from list

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am struggling with the serialization of a set of entries:

I have a set of of objects (*OpeningHours*) that are returned as JSON via an API endpoint. These objects are stored in a database and can be managed at client side.

Inside my API I need some kind of *virtual* objects. These objects do not really exist in database but are required for internal logic. They are part of the set but should not be returned to client. My approach was to use a custom `ContractResolver` and set the `ShouldSerialize` option based on if the object is virtual or not:

```cs
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(OpeningHours))
    {
        // Do not return virtual entries
        property.ShouldSerialize =
            instance => (instance.GetType().GetProperty(member.Name)?.GetValue(instance) as OpeningHours)?.Type != OpeningHoursType.Virtual;
    }

    return property;
}
```

The expected result is a list of openingHours objects as an array without the virtual entries.
My problem is that the `CreateProperty` method is never hit for the `OpeningHours` object itself - only for the child properties.

I also tried a customized json converter that will do nothing when the type is set to virtual. This works work in general but does not respect all my global serialization options (ignore defaults, camel case, ...)

So I am looking for a method that defines if a entry inside a list should be returned based on a certain value or a way to tell the parent of a property if it should be serialized or not. An option to use the default serialization settings in a custom converter would be fine as well. But as I see this is not possible by now.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just add `[JsonIgnore]` to those properties? (You might also want to consider separating the type used for JSON serialization from the type used for database storage. That involves some tedious work copying data around, but it does provide more flexibility in my experience.)

Comment: The `ShouldSerialize` function is for skipping entire properties of an object.  You want to skip specific entries in a collection, but Json.NET does not have builtin functionality for that.  To do that see [Excluding specific items in a collection when serializing to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20955722/3744182).  Does that answer your question, or do you need more specific help?

Comment: JsonIgnore attribute should work, if you need to apply logic to ignore/not ignore set a custom attribute where you can check if it should be ignored.
NewtonSoft JSON has a built-in feature for that: public bool ShouldSerializeINSERT_YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME_HERE()
{
    if(someCondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for your comments and sorry for late feedback. @JonSkeet: `[JsonIgnore]` will not help because it ignores properties in general. What I want to do is to not serialize specific entries based on a property.
@dbc: Thanks for the related question. That is what I tried with the custom converter. It works but does not respect my global serialization settings. If there is any solution for that, this would be my preferred solution.
@PowerMouse: The `ShouldSerialize` methods cannot be used for the same reason as I cannot use `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: I suspect using the term "virtual" here has been confusing - it certainly has been to me. (On a second read, it makes more sense.) I think it would be helpful to have a [mcve] and to a similar scenario but without using a term which typically has a very different meaning.

Comment: A simple option would be to serialize, then load the serialized form as a JObject, remove the entries you don't want, and then reserialize. That won't be particularly *efficient*, but it would get the job done.